# rigging movement of cad machine with bone constrains

Tags: animation, rigging, bone.constraints

I would like to animate the movements of this machine here with Blender.

Animation video link:
https://youtube.com/shorts/NI7p6CnXp1E?si=lVzzqbpwJB9x2Qjj

How do I go about it? Where do I start? Should I use inverse kinematics here? How do I set my bones and how do I define the possible rotation for each joint?
I really need help.[enter link description here](https://youtube.com/shorts/NI7p6CnXp1E?si=lVzzqbpwJB9x2Qjj)

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Chassis, Ctrl and ArmIK_Target bones are child of Root bone (Keep offset).

Arm01 is child of Chassis bone (keep offset).

Arm02 is child of Arm01 (connected).

Chassis bone has a Damped track bone constraint, targeting at Ctrl bone.

Arm02 has an IK Constraint, targeting at ArmIK_target, chain lenght = 2.

Ctrl bone is locked for moving on Z axis only.

Raising Ctrl bone will make the rig act as in ref video.

You will have to set a driver from chassis rotation to implement the further rotation of the top part of the machine.